# In Visual Studio 2019 is it possible to cause line numbers to be embedded in a .obj file?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2019

MS documentation for VS2019 says:

"The /Z7 option produces object files that also contain full symbolic debugging information for use with the debugger. These object files and the built executable can be substantially larger than files that have no debugging information. The symbolic debugging information includes the names and types of variables, as well as functions and line numbers. No PDB file is produced."

As I recall documentation for VS2015 and VS2017 said /Z7 was deprecated, but VS2019 would appear to have restored it.

However, neither of the following command lines (nor any of many variations I've tried) creates an obj with embedded line numbers.  Also, contrary to the documentation, the first line creates a PDB.

"cl -nologo -Z7 -Od -FoC:\Temp\FX2E070.obj -GS- -LD C:\Temp\FX2E070.c"

“cl -c -nologo -Z7 -Od -FoC:\Temp\FX2E070.obj -GS- C:\Temp\FX2E070.c"

I REALLY need those line numbers in my obj's.  Any help you can provide would bed great.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi, did you check this document about the  `/Z7` option.You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019). In VS2019, you can right-click on your project-->`Proeprties`-->`Configuration Properties`-->`C/C++`-->General-->set `Debug Information format` to `C7 compatible(/Z7)`. After that, do not forget to click `Apply`.

Comment: Yes, I know the document you mentioned.  The quote I included above is from it.  Regarding setting project properties, I'm not using (read "can't use") a project.  I need to use command lines like the two examples above.

Comment: Since you mentioned it, I'm going to experiment with /Z7 in one of my projects.  Maybe it works better there than in a command line invocation.  Thank you!

Comment: The results of my experiment with the /Z7 option set in a project's properties are ...
It does not work!  
 - The one and only obj file in my test dll contained no line number information (per dumpbin).
 - A pdb was created.
This is exactly the same result as produced by command line invocation.

Comment: Perhaps you can try to use [/GL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/gl-whole-program-optimization?view=vs-2019) option with /Z7. Properties-->`Configuration Properties`-->`C/C++`-->`Optimization`-->`Whole Program Optimization` to `Yes(/GL)`.

Comment: Serious issue with /GL ,,, Optimized Visual Studio compiler code causes crashes in almost all of our modules.  That's quite annoying since VC6 produced solid optimized code for our stuff.

Comment: Thank you again for continuing to suggest ideas!!

Answer (score 0):

> In Visual Studio 2019 is it possible to cause line numbers to be
>   embedded in a .obj file?

In **Viual Studio 2019**, you do need to write that command line in **Properties**. There is an option to enable `C7 compatible(/Z7)`. You can check [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/z7-zi-zi-debug-information-format?view=vs-2019).

**Solution**

**1)** Right-click on your project-->`Proeprties`-->`Configuration Properties`-->`C/C++`-->`General`-->set `Debug Information format` to `C7 compatible(/Z7)`.

[image]

**2)** do not forget to click `Apply` to start it.